# How to pass C/CXX flags to an external project in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm using CMake to drive the build of a project, but there are some sub-projects that need to be built using autotools. I use the ExternalProject feature in CMake to build it, but I'm having trouble passing the complete set of default C/CXX flags to the configure script for the subproject.

Currently I just pass CMAKE_C_FLAGS, CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, etc. The issue is that this does not include the build_type specific flags, which leads to issues when compiling with debug info (for instance), as I have to manually propegate the -g flag.

Current external project config looks like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  openthread-build
  SOURCE_DIR ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR}
  BINARY_DIR ${openthread_BINARY_DIR}
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMAND ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR}/configure ${OPENTHREAD_CONFIGURE_OPTS}
        "CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
        "CPP=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -E"
        "CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}"
        "AR=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR}"
        "RANLIB=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB}"
        "NM=${CMAKE_NM}"
        "STRIP=${CMAKE_STRIP}"
        "CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
        "CPPFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
        "CXXFLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
        "LDFLAGS=${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}"
        "--host=${MACHINE_NAME}"
  BUILD_COMMAND ${OPENTHREAD_MAKE} ${OPENTHREAD_MAKE_ARGS}
  BUILD_ALWAYS ON
  DOWNLOAD_COMMAND  cd ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR} && ./bootstrap
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

Problem lines are the ones like:

```
"CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
```

Which could ideally be something like `${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}}`, but that doesn't work due to case sensitivity of variable names.

```
"CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
```

So I guess the final option is to write a function which forms `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}`, converts it to upper and then expands that, but this seems quite clunky.

Is there any simple way to pass the default base set of C/CXX flags to an external project, without the need for manual hard-coding for each build type or adding functions? I expect the default CMAKE_C_FLAGS and the CMAKE_C_FLAGS_* for build type to be included.

Comment: I'm probably missing something here. The CMake documentation says that `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` already controls whether `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` or `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE` are included in `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`. Do you manually override that?

Comment: I Agree the CMake docs do say that, but it doesn't seem to happen in practice. I do use a toolchain file in the project I just mentioned, but I just tried another project without toolchain and got:
${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} = "", 
${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} = "-g", 
${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} = "Debug"

Comment: I also note that the actual files built with CMake are using the correct, full flags including the build_type ones.

Comment: I think that `CMake will see to having CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG settings get added to the CMAKE_C_FLAGS settings.` from `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` documentation may be poorly worded.  It doesn't update the variable `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` which would break multi-config generators.  It adds the per-config settings to the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` settings when used to generate the build files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am still open to other answers, but for now I have settled on creating an uppercase version of the build_type, and using that to extract the build_type specific flags.

```
# get an uppercase version of the build type, for extracting build_type specific flags
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    string(TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} BUILD_TYPE_UC)
endif()
```

So the individual flag lines look like:

```
"CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE_UC}} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
```

and the full externalproject call is pretty crowded but looks like:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  openthread-build
  SOURCE_DIR ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR}
  BINARY_DIR ${openthread_BINARY_DIR}
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMAND ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR}/configure ${OPENTHREAD_CONFIGURE_OPTS}
        "CXX=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
        "CPP=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER} -E"
        "CC=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}"
        "AR=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR}"
        "RANLIB=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB}"
        "NM=${CMAKE_NM}"
        "STRIP=${CMAKE_STRIP}"
        "CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE_UC}} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
        "CPPFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE_UC}} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
        "CXXFLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE_UC}} ${OPENTHREAD_INCLUDE_ARG}"
        "LDFLAGS=${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_${BUILD_TYPE_UC}}"
        "--host=${MACHINE_NAME}"
  BUILD_COMMAND ${OPENTHREAD_MAKE} ${OPENTHREAD_MAKE_ARGS}
  BUILD_ALWAYS ON
  DOWNLOAD_COMMAND  cd ${openthread_SOURCE_DIR} && ./bootstrap
  INSTALL_COMMAND   ""
  TEST_COMMAND      ""
)
```

Comment: The current behaviour if ``CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`` is empty is that the variable ``CMAKE_C_FLAGS_`` does not exist, so expands to nothing. If I follow your proposal @VictorSergienko , then the variable ``CMAKE_C_FLAGS`` would expand to the base set of flags, which are already included earlier in the line.